# Features not available in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

What are the features that are not available in T-SQL however, they are part of SQL standard. Also, If someone can list nice features that are available in PL/SQL (ORACLE) not currently available in T-SQL (e.g. LAG and LEAD etc.) I know Denali will introduce some of those (like lag and lead) but not sure?

I know there are features (some of those are indeed nice e.g. TOP) available in T-SQL but not part of SQL Standard. I just want to find other side of story.

Comment: Part of **WHICH** SQL standard?? There are so many..... ANSI or ISO? 1992, 1999, 2003, 2008 ??? The "Core" or the "full" set of feature???

Comment: "SQL standard" - you mean ANSI SQL or ISO?

Comment: Sounds like you want justification *not* to use SQL Server...

Comment: There are also some differences between MS T-SQL and Sybase T-SQL, so it might be necessary to specify which of the Transact-SQL's you want to target.

Comment: just wanted to ask capabilties that were limited in SQL server (T-SQL) that were available in standard SQL but I guess quesiton is too vague. I might infuriated some of you so I am sorry. – Cshah

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a SQL "standard".  However you can get O'Reilly SQL Pocket Guide, it has most of the primary differences between the SQL dialects and is well worth the 15 dollars to get.  There are many small differences in between TSQL and Oracle.  Too many to list here.

Comment: >>There really isn't a SQL "standard". SQL is a **standard** both ANSI and ISO I meant. I am not interested in small differences but features that offers big capabilities. like LAG and LEAD that you have to find a word around in TSQL

Comment: Actually: there are **way too many** SQL standards.....

Comment: I just wanted to ask capabilties that were limited in SQL server (T-SQL) but I guess quesiton is to vague. I might infuriated  you so I am sorry.